# Intellij language setting for keyboard key names

Tags: intellij-idea, internationalization

There is a funny behavior of IntelliJ that I have no idea how to change.

Whenever IntelliJ refers to a keyboard key, it gives the name in French.  Even though the user interface is otherwise set to English.

[image]

I know why it is French, it is because I am running a French version of Windows.  But it is still funny that key names are translated at all.

I tried to find a setting to change that but I was unable to find any kind of language setting.  It is difficult to find because "Language" refers to programming languages and "Internationalization" refers to the tools to translate an application, not the settings to configure IntelliJ itself.

Has anybody else been annoyed by this behavior and found a fix?

Comment: It should not be in French because you run a French Windows, it should be in French because you run a French keyboard layout. If you switch to a German layout, the names should be in German. If not, then that's an issue on IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After contacting JetBrains support, I got the following response:

> Serge Baranov (IntelliJ)
>   Jun 22, 21:04 CEST
>   Does it help if you add -Duser.language=en into .vmoptions
>   (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869)?

And yes, setting the language of the VM solved the problem.

Click Help > Edit Custom VM Options...  and add the option above at the end of the file.